# How occur the allocation of variable of type unsigned short and unsigned long in C programming language?

Tags: c, formatting

According the books, the variations of type integer occupy more or less bytes of memory, depending on the architecture, however the type unsigned short values ​​can get up to 65 535, since the type unsigned long 4 294 967 295.

So far so good, but when we think of the format placeholders, we can see which variations of int type like short and long have your own format placeholders; `%hd` and `%ld`, respectively.
This way we can know how many bytes will be reserved for this types, because we have we are aware that we are using explicitly the data types, however, for unsigned short and unsigned long types just there a single format placeholder: `%u`.

For me this means that I have no control about the number that will be set in this variable, I want mean, I must declare the variable like unsigned and the compiler will interpret if he number belongs to range of unsigned short or unsigned long.

What is the correct form of to declare variables of this types?

```
unsigned short <identifier_variable>;

unsigned short int <identifier_variable>;
```

or just:

```
unsigned <identifier_variable>;
```

and if the number belongs to range of the unsigned short type will reserve `2 bytes` for this variable, otherwise if the number assigned belong to unsigned long type all will work normally and the number of bytes reseved for this variable will be `4 bytes`.

Then, how I must doing this declarations and is there another format placeholders that I can't find in the GNU documentation?

Comment: What is your question? And is it in `C` or `C++`?

Comment: 1. choose C or C++, not both. 2. `unsigned` is same as `unsigned int`, `unsigned short` is same as `unsigned short int`

Comment: uintN_t <stdint.h> in C99. PRIuN <inttypes.h>.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I Just sign with the tag C++ due the fact of who programming C++ usually have much knowledge in C. I draw attention at title for C, but looking better this not seems a good practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So far so good, but when we think of the format placeholders, we can see which variations of int type like short and long have your own format placeholders; `%hd` and `%ld`, respectively. This way we can know how many bytes will be reserved for this types, because we have we are aware that we are using explicitly the data types, however, for unsigned short and unsigned long types just there a single format placeholder: `%u`.

Correction: unsigned short and unsigned long have `%hu` and `%lu`. Notice how these mirror the signed format placeholders. `%d` and `%u` are for signed and unsigned `int`s, respectively. The `h` and `l` modifiers change `int` to either `short` or `long`.

```
%hd     signed short
%hu   unsigned short
%d      signed int
%u    unsigned int
%ld     signed long
%lu   unsigned long
```

---

> What is the correct form of to declare variables of this types?
>
> ```
> unsigned short <identifier_variable>;
>
> unsigned short int <identifier_variable>;
> ```
>
> or just:
>
> ```
> unsigned <identifier_variable>;
> ```

The first two are equivalent. The last one `unsigned` means `unsigned int` rather than `unsigned short`.

Note that `short` is shorthand for `short int`, and `long` is short for `long int`. Also `signed` is implied, so `signed int` is the same as `int`. (Exception: `char` is not the same as `signed char`, it's a distinct type with implementation-defined signedness.)

Here are all the different ways of writing the basic integer types:

```
char
signed char
unsigned char
short          AKA signed short, signed short int
unsigned short AKA unsigned short int
int            AKA signed, signed int
unsigned       AKA unsigned int
long           AKA signed long, signed long int
unsigned long  AKA unsigned long int
```

Answer (score 1):

`%u` format specifier is specifying that the variable content should be parsed as unsigned value. You can combine that with length sub-specifier, so you can have `%hu` (for `unsigned short`), `%lu` (for `unsigned long`), etc.

There is a nice table available here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 1):

> for unsigned short and unsigned long types just there a single format placeholder: %u.

No. For `unsigned sort` the format specifier used is `%hu` while `%lu` is used for `unsigned long`.

### C11: 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions:

> `h`   Specifies that a following `d, i, o, u, x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a
> `short int` or `unsigned short int` argument (the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to `short int` or `unsigned short int` before printing); or that a following n conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `short int` argument.

---

> What is the correct form of to declare variables of this types?

First two are are correct declaration for `unsigned sort` type. But the third is wrong. It is equivalent to

```
unsigned int <identifier_variable>;
```

Answer (score 1):

About "placeholders" it will be useful to read the C Standard

> h Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier
>   applies to a short int or unsigned short int argument (the argument
>   will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its
>   value shall be converted to short int or unsigned short int before
>   printing); or that a following n conversion specifier applies to a
>   pointer to a short int argument.

As for the declarations then type specifier `unsigned` used alone is equivalent to `unsigned int`. If you want to declare an object of type unsigned short you have to specify the both simple specifiers

```
unsigned short SomeVariable;
```